# Passing parameter to Controller on click of a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I pass a parameter like

```
<input type="hidden" value= d.ID name="Action:Delete" class="btn-primary btn-sm"/>
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
```

back to the controller?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SubmitEmailList()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Request.Form["Action:Delete"] != null)
        {
            int id value = d.ID;

            using (Entities dbcontext = new Entities())
            {
                var UpDateRecord = (from a in dbcontext.AuthorisedEmailLists
                                    where a.ID == id
                                    select a).FirstOrDefault()
            }

            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
    }

    return CurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

The parameter I am trying to parse to the controller is `d.ID`

Comment: assuming you are doing a form submit, make sure your input element's name attribute value is same as the parameter name of your action method which handles the form submit.

Comment: How do I parse the parameter within the controller?

Comment: share the relevant part of your action method code. Is the above code you shared within a form ? where is it submitting to ?

Comment: Yes it's within a form

Comment: what is the `type` of the id value you want to pass ? Is it numeric or string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you shared, it will generate HTML markup like below

```
<input type="hidden" value="d.ID" name="Action:Delete" class="btn-primary btn-sm">
```

See, the value attribute is still a string `d.ID`! You probably want to use a `@` prefix if you are trying to get the `ID` property value of the object `d`

```
<input type="hidden" value="@d.ID" name="Action:Delete" class="btn-primary btn-sm"/>
```

The server side code you shared won't event compile, specifically the part where you are trying to read the value from the posted form data and assign it to a variable. The below should work.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitEmailList()
    {         
      if (Request.Form["Action:Delete"] != null)
      {
          var id = Request.Form["Action:Delete"];
          // id is of string type. Use id as needed.
      }
      // to do : return something
    }
```

Keep in mind that, the `Request.Form["Action:Delete"]` expression returns a `string`. If have a numeric value in that and want to convert it to `int`, You may use one of the helper methods like `Convert.ToInt32` or even better, `Int32.TryParse`

I personally do not try to explicitly read the `Request.Form`, instead levearage the MVC model binding. I can directly use an int type as the parameter as well (So no need of explicit conversion from string to numeric type).

For this, your input element's `name` attribute value should match with your action method parameter. Also make sure you are specifying the attribute values inside quotes(single or double)

```
<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("SubmitEmailList","YourControllerName")">
   <input type="hidden" value="@d.ID" name="id" class="btn-primary btn-sm"/>
   <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Now you may use

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SubmitEmailList(int id)
{
  // to do : use id (which is int type_.
  // to do : return something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is ok to have nested form?

Comment: nested forms are invalid. You should not have nested form!

Comment: Ok thanks, is it possible to pass the parameter just with the button?

Comment: Another option you can do is to convert it to an anchor tag, clicking on which will do a GET request to your controller action.

Comment: Thanks, I have implement as single form, but the parameter is being returned as a string!

Comment: are you trying to pass a numeric value or string value. use the appropriate type as parameter.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include @ within the value, everything is working ok, thanks again :)